# How to get the sequence in group-by for each unique group

Tags: xslt, group-by

```
<Dealer>
    <Vehicle>
        <Model>KA</Model>
        <Series>Type A</Series>
        <Price>1000.00</Price>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <Model>KA</Model>
        <Series>Type A</Series>
        <Price>1400.00</Price>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <Model>KA</Model>
        <Series>Type C</Series>
        <Price>1100.00</Price>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <Model>FOCUS</Model>
        <Series>Type C</Series>
        <Price>5000.00</Price>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
        <Model>FIESTA</Model>
        <Series>Type B</Series>
        <Price>6000.00</Price>
    </Vehicle>
</Dealer>
```

Need Output as:

```
KA Type A 1000.00 001
KA Type A 1400.00 001 
KA Type C 1100.00 002
KA Type C 5000.00 002
KA Type B 6000.00 003
```

where 001, 002 and 003 are the sequence for A, B and C

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current XSLT so we can fix it, instead of writing your code for you from scratch. Hint: you can use `position()`.

Comment: Please always tag XSLT questions with the specific version of XSLT that you are using. This is especially important when using grouping, which changes completely from XSLT 1.0 to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Within `xsl:for-each`, the `position()` function gives you the sequence number of the current group within the sequence of groups.

Comment: If I am using postion() inside for each , then below result is coming                                                                                                                            Type A 1000.00 001 KA                                                                                                          Type A 1400.00 002 KA                                                                                                        
Type C 1100.00 003  KA

Comment: but I need it at for-each-group-by level and using position() insidefor-each- group-by gives result as 001

Comment: @RichaKumari, if you have e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Dealer/Vehicle" group-by="Series"><xsl:variable name="group-pos" select="position()"/>...</xsl:for-each-group>` you should be able to output e.g. `001` using `format-integer($group-pos, '001')` (I think `format-integer` is new in XPath 3/XSLT 3) or using `format-number($group-pos, '001')` inside of the `for-each-group` or any nested instructions.

Comment: @RichaKumari We can tell you why your code doesn't work, but only if you show us your code.